# On the Representations of Free Algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

This is a statement from my text:
$A = k\langle x_1, \dots x_n \rangle$. Then a representation of $A$ is just a vector space over $k$ with a collection of arbitrary linear operators $\rho(x_1),\dots,\rho(x_n):V \to V$ (explain why!).

I'm in the process of showing that the map $F:\text{Rep}(A,V) \to \text{End}(V)^n$ given by $\rho \mapsto (\rho(x_1),\dots , \rho(x_n))$ is surjective.

From other discussions, I remember that a (unique) homomorphism $\rho$ exists where $\rho(x_i) = \rho_i$ via the universal property of free algebras. However I don't think I fully understand what this "universal property" is and I'm not certain on its ramifications or how to prove it. I'd like to have a better grasp on this.

Edit: $A = k\langle x_1 ,\dots , x_n\rangle$ is the free algebra on $n$ letters with product being the concatenation of words, with coefficients in a field $k$.

Comment: Please edit your post to include your definition of $A$.